# AngularJS resizable directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I had a directive in angularjs that handled adding jqueryui.resizeable() to a dom element. It was working correctly until we went through some of the other controllers and set them up to be compatible with IE8. (ex. we got rid of getters).

Now when i try to run my app (that was working before). I get the error message :

TypeError: undefined is not a function at postLink

Below is the code for my directive. Any ideas on why this is now happening?

html:

```
<div resizable id="container"></div>
```

directive:

```
angular.module('tffullscreen.directives').
    directive('resizable', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                callback: '&onResize'
            },
            link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.resizable({
                helper: 'resizeHelper',
                aspectRatio: true});
            elem.on('resizestop', function (evt, ui) {
                if (scope.callback) { scope.callback(); }
            });
            window.e = elem;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: is `elem` a jquery object? try `$(elem).resizable`. If that doesn't work.. isolate all function calls in your postLink function and see which one gives you the error. IE8 is a pain!

Comment: If i change to $(elem) I get error "$ not defined" ,after that just looking at the functions i am getting the error on elem.resizable ... keep in mind we optimized so code would run in IE8 but this test is being done in CHrome and FF which previously worked perfectly with this very directive.

Comment: `If i change to $(elem) I get error "$ not defined"` Im sorry, I assumed you had jquery loaded (because jquery UI needs jquery). If you include jquery before angular, the error will go away.

Comment: Nah its really more simple than that. . . This was working before and is working again. It wound up being an issue of bower and some dependencies ( namely jqueryui) not being in the right place . Its fixed now ... Thank you for taking a look at this